# Workaround for & and CRLF issue in Delphi XE4 with TXMLTransformProvider component

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I know its going to be a repeating question but still asking again as no workaround worked for this problem. Let me explain the problem statement first and then I will also mention what I tried.

**XML:**

```
<Order><XMLversion>2</XMLversion><Info>*-first line
*-second line</Info></Order>
```

`CRLF` is there after "*-first line" statement.

I created **XTR file** corresponding to this XML using Delphi XE4 RAD Studio **Tools --> XML Mapper** utility. Following XTR file I got:

```
<XmlTransformation Version="1.0"><Transform Direction="ToCds"><SelectEach dest="DATAPACKET\ROWDATA\ROW" from="\Order"><Select dest="@XMLversion" from="\XMLversion"/><Select dest="@Info" from="\Info"/></SelectEach></Transform><XmlSchema RootName="Order"><![CDATA[<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Order" type="OrderType"/>
  <complexType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="OrderType">
    <sequence>
      <element name="XMLversion" type="XMLversionType"/>
      <element name="Info" type="InfoType"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="XMLversion" type="XMLversionType"/>
  <simpleType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="XMLversionType">
    <restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </simpleType>
  <element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Info" type="InfoType"/>
  <simpleType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="InfoType">
    <restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </simpleType>
</xs:schema>]]></XmlSchema><CdsSkeleton/><XslTransform/><Skeleton><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?><DATAPACKET Version="2.0"><METADATA><FIELDS><FIELD attrname="XMLversion" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="1"/><FIELD attrname="Info" fieldtype="bin.hex" SUBTYPE="Text"/></FIELDS><PARAMS/></METADATA><ROWDATA/><METADATA><FIELDS><FIELD attrname="XMLversion" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="1"/><FIELD attrname="Info" fieldtype="bin.hex" SUBTYPE="Text"/></FIELDS><PARAMS/></METADATA><ROWDATA/></DATAPACKET>
]]></Skeleton></XmlTransformation>
```

**Problem Statement:**

In my dfm file, I put **TXMLTransformProvider** and **Clientdataset**. In TXMLTransformProvider, I have provided the path of XML and XTR files. ProviderName of TClientdataset is set to TXMLTransformProvider.

Following is my code to read "info" node from the XML.

```
procedure TfrmAmpersand.Issue;
var
  InfoNode : Variant;
begin
  try
    InfoNode := ClientDataset1.FieldByName('Info').AsVariant;
    ShowMessage(InfoNode);
  except on e:exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

There are two fields in XML: XMLVersion and Info. In Clientdataset, XMLVersion is TStringField while Info is of TMemoField.

ShowMessage(InfoNode), shows the message like this

```
*-first line&*-second line
```

While in case of Delphi 7, it works fine and shows message like this:

```
*-first line
*-second line
```

Following is my dropbox link where I have uploaded my sample project for this problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/foi7o3wf7wlx9lh/AmpersandIssue.zip

Please note, I have put hardcoded path for XML and XTR file in TXMLTransformProvider. So keep this project in D: drive or just change the path in TXMLTransformProvider.

Following is EDN link where I have asked same question but got no reply:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=667134&#667134

**Workarounds I tried:**

1. **Replace & with #13#10** after getting that node value.

   InfoNode := StringReplace(InfoNode, '&', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);

But this is not the right solution as info node can actually contain the & in database.

1. I tried all **Remy's solutions** which he provided in my last question:

I hardcoded my XML as:

```
<Order><XMLversion>2</XMLversion><Info>*-first line&#13;&#10;*-second line</Info></Order>
```

and

```
<Order><XMLversion>2</XMLversion><Info>*-first line&#xD;&#xA;*-second line</Info></Order>
```

and also

```
<Order><XMLversion>2</XMLversion><Info><![CDATA[*-first line
*-second line]]></Info></Order>
```

Nothing worked. Everytime I am getting the same result which I mentioned above. The ampersand sign.

1. **Ken White's** answer is also not working for me which he provided me in last question.
2. **@TLama** -  You suggested me in my previous question (sorry, but I have deleted that for some reason) that this is **bug in TXMLTransformProvider** and I should carry with Remy's solution. But now nothing is working. So what next steps should I take to solve this straight forward problem? Have you raised this bug with Embarcadero?

***Please suggest me any workaround which can solve this issue?***

Comment: Your problem sounds similar to a recent one asked by the OP of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688941/delphi-xe4-and-reportbuilder-15-tppmemo-field-issue.  I can't find the q I mean at the moment, but both Remy and Ken posted answers to this linked one that you may find helpful.

Comment: @MartynA - I tried all those answers and nothing is working. I am getting ampersand in each and every case as I explained in my question already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to preface this answer by saying that unlike Remy or Ken, I am absolutely no expert at Unicode, and I'm not even sure that it's involved in your problem.

However I've looked at the on-disk bytes that your XMLTransformProvider generates and compared it with what gets written to disk when you do a CDS.SaveToFile('Test.Xml', dfXML).

It's evident that whereas a CDS saves a newline embedded in a DB memo field as:

`&#013;&#010;`

what the XMLTransformProvider produces for a similar newline is:

`&#xA;`

So, my simple-minded suggested work-around is to wire in to your code where you open the XML datafile something like this, to load the CDS with XML in its own format:

```
const 
  TransformNewLine = '&#xA;';
  CDSNewLine = '&#013;&#010;';

function FixCdsXml(Input : String) : String;
begin
  Result:= StringReplace(Input, TransformNewLine, CDSNewLine, [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

procedure TfrmAmpersand.TestFix;
var
  S : String;
  SS : TStringStream;
begin
  S := XMLTransformProvider1.TransformRead.Data;
  S := FixCdsXml(S);
  SS := TStringStream.Create(S);
  try
    SS.Position := 0;
    ClientDataSet1.LoadFromStream(SS);
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

There don't seem to be any convenient events in TXMLTransformerProvider or its TXMLTransform sub-components to use as an opportunity to call TestFix automatically.  However, it does seem to work ok if you call it in the CDS's AfterOpen event, provided you add a "FixingXML" boolean to your form to prevent re-entrancy and code the event like this:

```
procedure TfrmAmpersand.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if FixingXML then exit;
  FixingXML := True;
  try
    TestFix;
  finally
    FixingXML := False;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using XE6, btw.

Comment: I tried your fix on my machine and its working finally :). Going to try it on my real project and will verify that no other issue is created due to this fix.

Comment: perfect answer! saved me from even more headache on this problem.